# Are mangled items any good?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So for various reasons my dwarves just fought off two Forgotten Beasts at once while a goblin siege looked on.  One of the Beasts knocked over some doors on the way in, so I have a bunch of mangled `XXdoorsXX` and mechanisms.  Surprisingly it seems I can use them like regular doors etc, even though they've been trampled by some beasts from the deeps.  Is this a terrible idea?  I get that good mechanisms are important for weapon traps, but is there anything else that I need them for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like most things, quality affects how other dwarves perceive value from items, including doors, windows, and most other things.

As far as I know, there is not a *negative* value modifier for things below regular quality. That would mean that your mangled doors are perfectly serviceable - they just won't make any nearby dwarves stop and ponder: "Damn. That is a fine, door!" anymore.

Depending on the original door quality, they may not have been doing that in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

The items are perfectly serviceable; but beware!

Any subsequent attack will see the doors being destroyed faster than would shiny new ones.

Comment: This is important; the damage done by building destroyers is considered deterioration, so a door being attacked by a building destroyer becomes a xdoorx, then a XdoorX, then a XXdoorXX before finally disappearing, although it has a decent chance of being deconstructed (falling over) before then, at which point the BD will stop hitting it. However, artifacts are IMMUNE to deterioration, so if you want a BD-proof door, an artifact is the way to go if you're lucky enough to get one.